# Request server using Axis2 RPC way, parameter order in xml packets not correct

Tags: cxf, apache-axis, adb, webservice-client

For example, I will send an object Fruits to server side.

The code like this:

```
public static <T> T call(String url, String ns, String method, Fruits fruits, Class<T> clz) throws AxisFault
{
  RPCServiceClient client = new RPCServiceClient();
  Options option = client.getOptions();
  EndpointReference erf = new EndpointReference(url);
  option.setTo(erf);
  QName name = new QName(ns, method);
  Object[] object = new Object[]{fruits};
  Class[] returnTypes = new Class[]{clz};
  Object[] reto = client.invokeBlocking(name, object, returnTypes);
  T t = (T)reto[0];
  return t;
}
```

The object like this:

```
public class Fruits implements Serializable
{
  private int pear;
  private int banana;
  private int apple;

  public int setPear(int pear){this.pear=pear;}
  public int getPear(){return this.pear;}
  ...
}
```

The xml part should be this:

```
...
<fruits>
  <pear>10</pear>
  <banana>20</banana>
  <apple>60</apple>
</fruits>
...
```

But in fact like this:

```
...
<fruits>
  <apple>60</apple>
  <banana>20</banana>
  <pear>10</pear>
</fruits>
...
```

Axis2 makes object's property alphabetical order, but the server doesn't accept. I can't modify the serverside, it is ESB.

The only way to do a success request is to use the Axis2 generated code, I used to use WSDL2Java, but too many redundant code and difficult to maintain. So I want refactor.

I have also tried to use CXF, but it also makes object's property alphabetical order, not followed with WSDL/XSD or DTO defined style.

I've find the reason why CXF makes the ordering, it uses java.beans.BeanInfo to get properties of object, such as:

```
...
BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Fruits.class);
PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
...
```

The property in the array has already alphabetical order.

Who knows how to let Axis2 to serialize the Fruits' property to be correct ordering.

Thank you, the first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on Axis2, but if you are using CXF with the JAXB databinding, you can add an annotation like:

```
@XmlType(name = "fruits", propOrder = { "apple", "banana", "pear" }})
```

to the Fruits class to tell JAXB what order you need/want them output.

Comment: It works, thank you!
However, there is another problem. Packets returns an xml data, but is not bind to returned object